# Eclipse startup error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse encountered this error on startup after installing Jaspersoft plugin:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-07-19 14:05:02.890
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/Node
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl.createXMLLoad(XMIResourceImpl.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.createXMLLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:166)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.Node cannot be found by org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.10.2.v20150123-0348
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: I've removed the org.w3c.dom.svg.patch_1.1.0.jar and my Eclipse starts

Answer (score 4):

I also got same problem, after install Jaspersoft Studio as plugin in Eclipse 4.2.2, using Jaspersoft Studio Update Site - http://jasperstudio.sourceforge.net/updates/

I don't know why/how but it work on me, following steps:
  - I check for file '**org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.10.2.v20150123-0348**' (@alok-ray), it does exist but eclipse still error when run.
  - I delete it or move it to different location, then run eclipse (it will show another error and close)
  - Restore that file, run eclipse again. Working !

I hope this can help.

Comment: I didn't find Jaspersoft plugin very useful. However the above solution worked fro me. Thanks

Comment: for me the following worked: 1. rename `eclipse\plugins\org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar` to `*.*_`, 2. start eclipse (aborts with another error), 3. rename back the file from 1., 4. start eclipse => done

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse might have crashed so Please check the Jar in eclipse is present or not in path "eclipse\plugins" , File Name '**org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.10.2.v20150123-0348**' . 
If its their then close the eclipse and try to reopen the eclipse again.

If it doesn't work out the try to remove the Jaspersoft Plugin and restart again. There might be issue in the plugin or installation error.

Adding more suggestions

> Eclipse may have crashed sometime before and is unable to restore the workspace (the metadata stored by the eclipse might be corrupted).
>
> So try to use a new workspace. To force the workspace window prompt you need to change the settings in the file.
>
> File Name : \configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs 
>   and set SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG to true (use Notepad++ to edit).
>
> After that you can import all your projects to the new workspace..

If you still getting issues in startup , please post some pics and exact eclipse exit code.. we can dig more on to it..

Comment: how to remove the Jaspersoft plugin and eclipse cannot start?

Comment: Please let me know the eclipse return exit code, you are getting?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. And I am not able to open my eclipse. so how should I disable.deactivate jasperplugin to get this problem out ??

infact i want to use jaspersoft plugin, so please suggest what we can do get this work.